# What is the difference between a composite data type and a data structure?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, types

I read that a character array in C is a composite data type because it is a sequence of characters, but then in Java a String is a class and Wikipedia says that a class is data structure, I am confused.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Data structure" is a very general term of theoretical computer science.  Any technique for the organization of machine-manipulable data can be thought of as a data structure.  Even a single machine integer is a data structure, because there's more than one way that the bits could be interpreted.  Most often, though "data structure" is used to refer to the organization applied to a *large* collection of data: for instance, a binary tree, a hash table, a flat array, or a linked list.  And usually when people talk about data structures they do it in generic terms, not specific to a particular programming language.

"Composite data type" is a term-of-art of C and related languages, meaning "any language data type that isn't a machine number", more or less.  Composite data types are data structures, but not all data structures are composite data types -- machine numbers are too simple to be composite data types, and a complex data structure is likely to be built out of *several* composite data types.

"Class" is a term-of-art of object-oriented programming languages, referring to a data type that defines not only data but "methods" for manipulating the data.  In C++, all class types are composite data types, but not all composite data types are class types (the others are "plain old data", or "POD", types).

"String" is the generic term for a data structure that holds a sequence of small machine integers that somehow represent text.  Just about every programming language has some notion of a string, but no two of them are the same.  Strings are by definition data structures.  In the C family, strings are always composite data types, because a *single* machine integer is not big enough for more than a few characters.  In object-oriented programming languages, strings are usually, but not always, class types.

I hope this at least advances you to a more sophisticated level of confusion.

Answer (score 3):

a datatype is any thing you can make a variable out of.
a member is a variable.
a method is a function.
a base type has no members and no methods in it.
a struct is composed of combinations of base types and other structures.
a class is a struct that includes methods as well as members.
an array is an array of any datatype, either of base types, structs, or classes.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'd say "composite data type" and "data structure" are pretty much the same thing: a piece of data with distinguishable parts, as opposed to simple or elementary data types like char or byte which are not made up of smaller data types.

Answer (score 0):

Every Data Type is a Data Structure but nor every data structure is a data type.

A data type is an entity that can hold data.
A data type of the simplest form is a primitive data type.
A more complex data type made up of primitive data types is a composite data type

A Data structure becomes different from a data type when it hold Relationships between the entities stored, along with the entities. 
here the entities are the data types. but the data types together with the relationships form the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Composite types are derived from more than one primitive type (chars, ints, boolean, etc). This can be done in a number of ways. The ways they are combined are called data structures.

Therefore, your character array in C is a composite data type and a data structure. In general, to make your life and the lives around you easier, you can see a data structure as a generic term.