# Are classes and structures both subsets of "records"?

Tags: terminology

I'm writing documentation for my AQA A-level Computing project. The project is a game which takes place in a Console application, which heavily depends on a series of classes and structures in a separate class library I have written. I don't know how to title the section in my documentation where I describe these classes and structures, and I'd like to know if there is a word that encompasses both concepts. Does the word "record" include both classes and structures, or is it tied to a specific implementation?

I'm aware that this is more English Language & Usage, but I thought it was more likely to get a response here where there are more programmers.

Comment: This may be better suited for [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) or [english](http://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @bwtrent, I've edited the OP, does that explain a bit better what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I've also posted it on EL&L if 3 more people wish to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could use the term `record` as objects/classes/structures are just differing types of records, or records with functions to handle the data in the record.

However, just to encapsulate all your possibilities, you should probably utilize the term `Data Structure`. I find that `data structure` is more common parlance than `record`.

Comment: Thank you, that's just what I needed. Are enumerated types also considered data structures, per interest?

Comment: @LeoKing, I believe an enumeration type would be a `Data Type`. Check this other [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630377/explain-the-difference-between-a-data-structure-and-a-data-type)